# Given a table with a varchar column, return the entries that do not have any suffix in a different row

Tags: sql, string, select

Example: A query on a table containing the following strings -

```
----------
| abcd    |
----------
| abc     |
----------
| bcda    |
----------
| bcdag   |
----------
| bc      |
----------
```

Would output

```
--------
| abcd |
--------
| bcdag|
--------
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT col
FROM   mytbale a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   mytable b
                   WHERE  a.col <> b.col AND 
                          a.col LIKE CONCAT(b.col, '%'))
```

Comment: . . . `and a.col <> b.col`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff arg, of course. Nice catch! Edited and fixed.